# phonegap android video capture

Tags: cordova, video, capture

I am using this code for android:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.***,
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    mediaType:Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
    });
```

However, I can only capture photos but the video capture option is disabled. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Capture Video using Phonegap**

Try to change

```
 var options = { limit: 1, duration: 10 };
 navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(videoSuccess, videoError, options);
```